# Remove a previous commit without touching files

Tags: git

Consider the following *unpushed* commits:

```
97874cd commit 5
13bc8cf commit 4
60c37d4 commit 3
0c29771 commit 2
6db9ba4 commit 1
```

How do I remove *commit 3* without touching any files at all and keeping commit 4 and 5 intact?

Comment: do an interactive rebase and squash the third commit

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer I am that afraid.

Answer (score 2):

Do you intend to keep the changes of commit 3, but have it disappear from your history? Then you should make an interactive rebase like so:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

And then mark 60c37d4 to be `smashed` or `fixed` during the rebase.

If you want to remove the changes of commit3 as well, delete the corresponding line in the interactive rebase. Another way to accomplish the latter is

```
git rebase --onto HEAD~3 HEAD~2 HEAD
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be:

```
git checkout -B new_branch
git reset --hard 0c29771
git cherry-pick 13bc8cf
git cherry-pick 97874cd
git checkout master
git reset new_branch
```

This will result in files in the same state as before any of these, but the changes of commit 3 will be uncommitted (assuming it all goes without any conflicts).

Comment: this is effectively a manual rebase, a good trick if you'r not familiar with rebasing :)

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer, if I remember it right, squash would add changes from the commit3 to whatever was the commit next to it. My understanding of what the OP wants was that he wants the changes of the commit 3 to become uncommitted, while commit 4 and commit 5 to be committed after commit 1 and commit 2.

Comment: @Ishamael Your statement is correct as to what I want.

Comment: @user2094178, then my solution should work :) the other answer is also probably correct, but I am not myself familiar with `smashed` in the interactive rebase. `cherry-pick`, as properly pointed out above, is a nice safe option if you don't want to understand details of the interactive rebase.